# Polymer 1.0 strange behaviour on properties

Tags: polymer

I'm just learning polymer (1.0) so please bear with me.

I'm using express.js to return some array of JSON.stringified items and for-each them, so the result is as follows (in HTML):

`<fighter-profile fighter="{&quot;country&quot;:&quot;USA&quot;,&quot;countryFullName&quot;:&quot;United States&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Frank Mir&quot;,&quot;nickname&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zuffa_record&quot;:{&quot;wins&quot;:&quot;15&quot;,&quot;losses&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;draws&quot;:0,&quot;no_contest&quot;:0}}"></fighter-profile>`

it seems ugly as hell, but that's json.

Here's my component:

```
<dom-module id="fighter-profile">

  <template>
    <div>

      <paper-item>
        <paper-item-body two-line>
          <div>{{fighter.name}}</div>
          <div secondary>{{nickname}}</div>
          <div>
            <paper-button raised on-click="handleClick">Show nickname</paper-button>

          </div>
        </paper-item-body>
      </paper-item>

    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'fighter-profile',

      properties: {
        fighter: Object,
        nickname: {
          type: String,
          value: 'testing'
        }
      },

      ready: function() {
       this.nickname = (this.fighter.nickname !== '') ? this.fighter.nickname : '... the dude has no nickname!'; 
      },

      handleClick: function() {
        alert(this.nickname);
      }

    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Now, the funny part: the name gets displayed properly, while where I have the `<div secondary>{{nickname}}</div>`, the result in HTML is literally `{{nickname}}`; however, if I click on button, I get the correct value.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I've googled some stuff, and replaced `ready` method with `created` and, of course, it didn't work, since `created` I think is part of Polymer 0.5 version. Then I switched back to `ready` method and now everything works as expected. Very odd.

What seems to be the problem? Some caching gone wrong? a bug?

**UPDATE 2:**

I've changed some stuff again and it doesn't work, but now I've figured out how to replicate the mistake. So, this piece of code DOESN'T work correctly:

`<div secondary>The dude is also known as {{nickname}}</div>`
the result is literally "{{nickname}}"

However, this works correctly:

`<div secondary>The dude is also known as  <span>{{nickname}}</span></div>`
the result is the actual nickname.

So, putting properties in `span` tag renders it correctly. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things I think I can help you with here.  First, you can make your JSON much more readable by using single quotes for your attributes.  Additionally, you can include white space, if you are hard-coding the JSON:

```
<fighter-profile
  fighter='{
    "country":"USA",
    "countryFullName":"United States",
    "name":"Frank Mir",
    "nickname":"",
    "zuffa_record":{
      "wins":"15",
      "losses":"9",
      "draws":0,
      "no_contest":0
    }
  }'></fighter-profile>
```

Next, I'm going to assume that the JSON is actually *not* hard-coded, and bound to another data source.  I make this assumption because it seems like your `fighter` property is not available in `ready`, as you are expecting it to be.  A common issue I see in cases such as this is something like the following:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="fighter">
  <fighter-profile fighter="{{fighter}}"></fighter-profile>
</template>
```

The thing to keep in mind in the above case is that `<fighter-profile>` is created, readied, and attached to the DOM before the parent element assigns `fighter` to its `fighter` property.

To remedy this, you can make use of observers which perform tasks automatically when the data gets loaded into a property:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'fighter-profile',
    properties: {
      fighter: Object,
      nickname: {
        type: String,
        value: 'testing'
      }
    },

    observers: [
      // This tells Polymer to watch `fighter` and fire the
      // _fighterUpdated method only after `fighter` receives
      // a value **other than undefined.**
      '_fighterUpdated(fighter)'
    ],

    _fighterUpdated: function(fighter) {
      this.nickname = (this.fighter.nickname || '... the dude has no nickname!');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Next, binding properties to HTML.  When you bind to HTML contents, such as with `<div>{{property}}</div>`, what Polymer (currently) does behind the scenes is bind `property` directly to `div.innerText`.  Polymer also only checks the first two characters of innerText to see if it's a `{{` or `[[`, and does not do anything if it doesn't find them.

The Polymer team is working to make binding more robust, but so far as I know they haven't announced any concrete plans or timelines.  For the time being, the solution is as you've discovered, just wrap an inline binding in `<span>` =)

Comment: ahh yes! now it all makes sense, especially the binding properties to HTML part. Yes, the data is gathered dynamically, in a `{{#each}}` part of handlebars (via express.js), so I can't do much about the JSON. Now for the `observers` part; I needn't do that, and it still works... can you please clarify a bit what that does or how can I recreate a scenario where - without that part - things wouldn't work? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you are looping through the data on the server side. In that case my comment about raw JSON vs binding would not apply, and the data would be immediately available in `ready`.  I have updated my answer to clarify the scenario, which now shows a common use case for `dom-repeat` to loop through data on the client side.

Comment: Thanks! One last question and then I can easily accept your answer: is there a documentation for this? I didn't see a case for `as="someValue"`, the official documentation has only `<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">`.

Comment: Certainly, you can read about the `as` property here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#nesting-templates